# How to Compare TBlobField OldValue with Value

Tags: delphi

In Delphi 2010,

```
if Field.OldValue <> Field.Value then
...
```

raises the Exception:

> raised exception class
>   EVariantTypeCastError with message
>   'Could not convert variant of type
>   (Array Byte) into type (Integer)'.

How can I know if a TBlobField value has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with

```
if Field is TBlobField then
  Result := TBlobField(Field).Modified
```

Comment: This can be extended to: if Field.DataType in Low(TBlobType)..High(TBlobType)] then Result := TBlobField(AField).Modified. TBlobType is defined in unit Data.DB in Delphi XE2

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
if Field is TBlobField then
  Result := TBlobField(Field).Modified
```

allows you to detect if the field was changed, but still does not allow you to obtain the oldValue, if you need to detect WHAT was changed and not IF something was changed.